# flash .swf file run in java swing

Tags: java, flash

how to load flash swf inside jlabel of swing in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load it as a image in a label, but there is an implementation of embedding Flash in Swing using [JFlashPlayer](http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer/)

Note that a previous question, with this and other answers is the first result in a google query for 'flash embed java swing'. Google is often a lot quicker than submitting a question...

Comment: There's also an external Flash API (not sure whether JFlashPlayer uses that or has its own brew) you could possibly try to interact with. It's a horrible idea nevertheless though and probably more trouble than it's worth. Random inclusion of Flash content is half the reason Adobe's GUIs are so bloody inconsistent.

Comment: Could you invoke .swf (i.e.   .fla -- compiled action script code)?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bad idea.

but anyway read lots of java and flash integration on
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/java/cross_product_integration.html

Comment: why it is bad idea .   if it is really a bad idea gimme alternateve i will drop this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You try API DJ NativeSwing look at here: https://dzone.com/articles/dj-nativeswing-reloaded-jwebbr

```
 JFlashPlayer flashPlayer = new JFlashPlayer();
    flashPlayer.setURL(myFlashURL);
```